# Как создавать файл с данными из чека при его оформлении?

Tags: 1с

Как при каждом создании чека в 1С создавать либо Excel-файл, либо какой-то похожий с данными этого чека?

Answer (score 0):

В конфигурации 1С, создайте *Подписку на событие* "Запись - документа чек", внутри которой сохраняйте все необходимые данные в файл;
Код можно поместить в Расширение.

Comment: А можете подсказать где написан код на подобие того, что мне нужен

Comment: см: https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1098803/